# How can I change the font of ListView?

Tags: android, listview, fonts

I need some assistance on how to change my `ListView` font.
I have searched and checked out some answers but I don't really understand it.

I have successfully changed the TextView by using the following code:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/roboto.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf ,1);

    }
```

But I want to change the `ListView` element font, is there any way to do it like mentioned above?

Comment: write your own custom adapter, and in that getview method inflate the row with a xml file and in that set your own font

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a custom listView adapter. and you can change the font in that adapter. Check this site to know how to use custom adapter http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        Your_Class_Name.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, Your_Array_List) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView) view
                .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        // You do here whatever you want with textView

        return view;
    }
};
```